# systemctl authenticating as other user

Tags: linux, systemd, services, authentication, systemctl

I have made this script that allows non-root access for a directory so a program can make changes to files in said directories. This .service has worked on a few machines and even on the same machine in the past however after a fresh reinstall of arch linux `systemd`/`systemctl` is "Authenticating as: mpd".

The weird thing is when i use `sudo` to start it. It will work but using enable doesn't persist on reboot.

I'm don't really know what I'm doing so i apologize I'm gonna read up on systemd after the semester.

```
[oddstap@Arch2019 ~]$ systemctl enable brightlight.service
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-unit-files ====
Authentication is required to manage system service or unit files.
Authenticating as: mpd
Password:
polkit-agent-helper-1: pam_authenticate failed: Authentication failure
==== AUTHENTICATION FAILED ====
Failed to enable unit: Access denied
[oddstap@Arch2019 ~]$
```

I'm not really sure why this is I've tried a few things like using the `--user` flag and then giving the exact directory. It has mixed results/ Ive also tried putting the service file in `/etc/systemd/system` that just does the same thing.

```bsh
[oddstap@Arch2019 /usr/lib/systemd/system]$ systemctl --user enable /usr/lib/systemd/system/brightlight.service
Removed /home/oddstap/.config/systemd/user/multi-user.target.wants/brightlight.service.
Created symlink /home/oddstap/.config/systemd/user/multi-user.target.wants/brightlight.service → /usr/lib/systemd/system/brightlight.service.
[oddstap@Arch2019 /usr/lib/systemd/system]$
```

I've seen a similar issue I think [on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/841306/authentication-is-required-to-manage-system-services-or-units).

Here is the .service file I posted it here I'm pretty sure this is not the cause but I could be wrong. I'm gonna try to fix this but if anyone got any ideas let me know. Not having systemd enabling scripts is making my life hard.

```
[Unit]
Description Hopefully will be a solution for you reading.
Before nodered.service

[Service]
Type oneshot
User root
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "/bin/chmod a+w /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/*"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: I've never seen systemd specifiers without `=` (e.g. `Before=` etc.). Could you confirm that this is not the root of the error? It might not be understood where to put it if the `Before=` statement is not noticed properly.

Comment: Good idea I also think I've found a fix for it authenticating as mpd but it's crude. Basically I think unistalling mpd and removing the user and reinstalling it has fixed it but I'm not completely sure yet the service is authenticating as root now but the service still doesn't work on reboot

Comment: Apart from that: a user cannot just run a service as `root` ro with `User=root` - for obvious security reasons. So if you use `--user` the start must fail if you do not specify the permission before. Second, enabling system-wide services is a `root` privilege, so use `sudo` or do it as `root`.

Comment: OK that makes sense I mean I usually do use sudo before enabling a service but I just tried different things to see if I could get more information about why it's not working. Makes sense though. I tried your suggestion adding Before= it still doesn't work so I'm just gonna keep trying to get it to work but if you have any ideas about how I should go about doing this I'd appreciate it otherwise thanks for all your help I appreciate it

Comment: Well, add the `=` for all specifiers first, try to start the service and check if it returns errors or runs smoothly, (`systemctl status <service>`). Also use `journalctl -u <service>` and see if you can get information regarding the (non-) starting of the service.

Comment: I did do that thanks for telling me to use the -u flag that helped I was just using grep. From what I can see it almost works but I'm not executing the command correctly. Chmod missing operand. Some I'm gonna try and fix it and get back to you.

Comment: OK so basically the service itself works but for some reason chmod is saying there is no such file or directory. However I check it and the directory does exist. Idk this is so weird

Comment: `/sys` like `/run` or `/dev` are temporary file systems created dynamically and changed depending on your current setup. I assume your service runs before they are properly populated.

Comment: i didn't know that but that makes a lot of sense I've tried just about everything to get this to work even making the service run a script with the command instead of running it in the service. i have no idea why its not working but if the service is running before the directories exist it makes sense. but i wonder what changed between a fresh install of arch? maybe we should use the chat if you interested in continuing talking im not an expert at using this site but its telling me not to abuse the comments.

Comment: No worries - extended comments happen. Try to add the following to your `[Service]`: `Restart=on-failure` and `RestartSec=30s` which does exactly what you think every 30 seconds until the service succeeds.

Comment: Sounds great I'll give a try thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

Well I'm gonna leave my question up just in case anyone can figure out a proper fix for this. I was able to fix it by uninstalling mpd then deleting the mpd user and reinstalling it. its crude but if anyone else can figure out a better way to do this or even why this happens in the first place id appreciate it.